# Dock a control in native C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I know how to do this in .Net but in native Win32, how does one dock a control. I'm trying to dock a trackbar I made like vlc's trackbar.

Thanks

dock it to the bottom of its parent window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write the code to do it, or use a library which provides that functionality. If you are intent on using raw Win32, handle the WM_SIZE message for the container, calculate where the trackbar should be, and put it there. Roughly (0,height-trackbar_height,width,trackbar_height).

Apparently, [Pearl Jam](http://www.pearljam.com/tour) are still touring.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was a Win32 API thing